# How to divide an interval into geometrically increasing sub-intervals

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

It'll be obvious when I see the answer, but I'm too tired/thick to figure it out.
If I have a certain time period, and I want to divide it into a given number of geometrically increasing (or decreasing) durations so that the ratio of interval(n)/interval(n-1) is constant, then how do I figure out the ratio and/or the starting duration of the first interval?

For example if you wanted to divide a 15-second period into 4 increasing durations you might get the geometric series 1, 2, 4, 8 (where the ratio is 2, and start duration is 1 second)

I think it's something to do with log(T)/N, where T is the total time and N is the number of divisions, but that's as far as I've got.

Comment: The ratio and start value are not uniquely determined (you have to choose at least one). That is unless you put some additional constraints, such as both being integers or something, but than you don't have guarantee this will have a solution for all $T$. This is just sum of geometric progression $a\frac{r^N-1}{r-1}=T$, so choose $a$ and compute $r$, or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks, had no idea there was a closed form of the sum of a geometric progression (although I suspected it :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have an interval of length L and you want to divide it into N intervals $I_k$ s.t. $I_k/I_{k-1} =q$ for $k=1,..N-1$. Then the length of each interval can be written as $cq^k, k=0,...,N-1$, where $c>0$ is some constant and $$ L= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} cq^k = c \frac{1-q^N}{1-q}$$
You would have to solve this for fixed N, which is not trivial when N>2.

Comment: Thanks, I should have specified that either the ratio is given or start duration is known. Then it's a simple calculation to get the other value, now that you've given me the closed form.